# How can I change the FOV in a persistent way when playing Source Engine games?

Tags: source-engine

No More Room in Hell is a source mod, so the console command "fov 90" should work, although I did not test it.

But how can I change it via the commandline, what is the proper command for source games to alter the FOV every time I launch it?

Comment: Does it have to be via command line? You can likely set it in a config file or startup script.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think games can change what Source commands do.  One example is trying `sv_cheats 1` in [tag:the-stanley-parable], which responds with the "Serious Ending".

Comment: @ColinD It is the usual way to do it. The launch options also get saved in the cloud afaik. I can also put it in the autoexec, I am just searching for the correct command.